# $fdz \otimes d\bar z \in H^1(X,\Omega)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be, for example, a compact Riemann surface. As we know, $fd\bar z\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ can be a representative of $H^1(X,T_X)$, then, why not $fd\bar z\otimes dz$ be a representative of $H^1(X,\Omega)$? Since we usually choose $fdz\wedge d\bar z$ as its representative, then can we say $fd\bar z\otimes dz$ is another representative of $H^1(X,\Omega)$? If the answer is yes, then does it means there exists an isomorphism between $fd\bar z\otimes dz$ and $fd\bar z\wedge dz$?

Comment: Can you provide the source where $f dz\wedge d\bar z$ is used?

Comment: @Arctic Char, when we want to prove the Dolbeault cohomology $H_{\bar \partial}^{p,q}(X)=H^q(X,\Omega^p)$, the representatives used are forms, see for example Chern's book 《complex manifolds》p30.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't $fdz\wedge d\bar{z}$ just the local expression for a representative of a class in $H^{1,1}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ while $fd\bar{z}\otimes dz$ is the local expression for a representative of a class in $H^1(X, \Omega)$? These two groups are isomorphic and the isomorphism changes one expression to the other.

Comment: @Michael Albanese, your comment seems quite reasonable, so, generally, can we say $A^{p,0}\otimes A^{0,q}$ is isomorphic to $A^{p,0}\wedge A^{0,q}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a complex manifold. The complexified tangent bundle $T_{X, \mathbb C} = T_{X, \mathbb R} \otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C$ splits as
$$T_{X, \mathbb C} = T_X^{1,0} \oplus T_X^{0,1},$$
and this splitting gives a splitting of the dual bundle $\Omega_X = \Omega_X^{1,0} \oplus \Omega_X^{0,1}$. This induces a decomposition
$$ \Lambda^n \Omega_X = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} \Lambda^p \Omega_X^{1,0} \otimes \Lambda^q \Omega_X^{0,1}.$$
Now the inclusion $\Lambda^p \Omega_X^{1,0} \otimes \Lambda^q \Omega_X^{0,1} \hookrightarrow \Lambda^n \Omega_X$ is given in local holomorphic coordinates $z_1, \dotsc z_n$ by the map $d z^I \otimes d \bar z^J \mapsto dz^I \wedge d \bar z^J$. So in this way we identify $dz^I \otimes d\bar z^J$ with $dz^I \wedge d \bar z^J$.

Comment: Do we define $dz\wedge d\bar z=dz\otimes d\bar z-d\bar z \otimes dz$? then for each $dz\otimes d\bar z$ there is a unique $dz\otimes d\bar z-d\bar z \otimes dz$ corresponding to it, and on the inverse side, it is the same, so we say there is an isomorphism?

Comment: @Tom No, the term $dz \otimes d \bar z - d \bar z \otimes dz$ does not make any sense in $\Omega^{1,0} \otimes \Omega^{0,1}$. In that tensor product, the $(1,0)$-part is always on the left, the $(0,1)$-part is always on the right. We identify $dz \otimes d \bar z = dz \wedge d \bar z$ via the natural inclusion given above.

Comment: Yes, but usually we do not define $\Lambda^n \Omega_X = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} \Lambda^p \Omega_X^{1,0} \otimes \Lambda^q \Omega_X^{0,1}$, maybe we can write it as $\Lambda^n \Omega_X = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} \Lambda^p \Omega_X^{1,0} \wedge \Lambda^q \Omega_X^{0,1}$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $\Lambda^P \Omega^{1,0} \wedge \Lambda^q \Omega^{0,1}$. If $V,W$ are any vector spaces, then for any $n$ the map $\bigoplus_{p+q=n} \Lambda^p V \otimes \Lambda^q W \to \Lambda^n(V \oplus W)$ defined on pure tensors by $v \otimes w \mapsto v \wedge w$ is an isomorphism (check this!). In this way we can identify $\Lambda^p V \otimes \Lambda^q W$ with a subspace of $\Lambda^n(V \oplus W)$.

Comment: Ok, by your definition, it is definitely right, but here I think the problem is to prove there is an isomorphism between the space spaned by {$dz\otimes d\bar z$} and the space spaned by {$dz\wedge d\bar z=dz \otimes d \bar z - d \bar z \otimes dz$}.

Comment: @Tom The isomorphism is the one given above, $dz \otimes d \bar z \mapsto dz \wedge d \bar z$.

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear!